# MVC5 use single ActionResult for multiple pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I searched longer than I care to admit for a solution, but cannot find one.

My site has hundreds of static pages.

It is very tedious to add a single ActionResult per View.

Especially because I have to stop debugging to edit the code.

So for example, if I want to add an About page I have to add...

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

It seems to me that I should be able to make this dynamic and pass the view in via the route.

I mean, as long as I have a file called About.cshtml, then why do I need to add a custom ActionResult.

I'd rather do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
    public ActionResult Index(_ViewName)
    {
        return View(_ViewName);
    }
```

Is it possible to have a generic ActionResult and pass the name of the view in via the URL Route?

Comment: *I'd rather do something like this, but it doesn't work.* - Elaborate? If you format the view name properly, there's absolutely no reason why this wouldn't work (assuming you have actually written code that compiles, rather than what you've posted).

Comment: To elaborate on that specific comment... I was saying it would be nice if I could pass the View into the ActionResult.  Any solution that allows me to have a single ActionResult would be great.  Now, you say that there is no reason it shouldn't work assuming I wrote the code and formatted the view name properly.  Well, that is the problem.  I don't know what code to write.  If you provided the code via a short example (perhaps show what the route and action result should look like), then it would be the answer to the question and I'd mark it as the answer.

Comment: But you have almost exactly the code you need already... except that you need to use a valid method signature - `public ActionResult Index(string viewName) { return View(viewName); }`

Comment: There is something else wrong with your code: you never described any further then "it doesn't work" , I have an answer identical to your code that in fact does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your default route you can edit `index` method as below and get it done.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

What you have to do is add the view according to the name you are parsing.

**Example**

```
/home/index/about
/home/index/contact
```

(`About.cshtml` and `Contact.cshtml` views should be in `/Views/Home/` folder)

Thanks!

Comment: It took me viewing the Example above to realize my idea worked, but I was testing it wrong.  I had the URL as /home/about.  So it really was as simple as the two kind people above tried to point out.  I am marking this as the answer because it included the URL example.